# Using Python scripts in Android for image processing

Tags: android, python

I have some python scripts which are doing image processing work using its own numpy and scipy libraries. How can I use/call these scripts in Android application providing image input from camera captures and saving the images after processed. Is there some native support for Python like C++. What performance implications would be there if I compare with using C++ as a native support. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please find suggestions on how to do this [via this link](https://www.google.de/search?q=python+in+android).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QPython](http://qpython.com/) to run python scripts in android. It's a powerful program. Or use [Kivy](http://kivy.org/) to develop cross platform apps with python. And a better solution is http://code.google.com/p/android-python27/ an embeded python iterpreter!!

Comment: Look at the updated answer about embedded python interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but QPython is an Android application that installs on device and has its own GUI, where python scripts can be executed. What I want is to execute python scripts in my apk to manipulate images. If you can suggest on embedding Python Interpreter in my Android application to do this task.

Comment: As I said you can use an embedded python interpreter in your android project look at this link http://code.google.com/p/android-python27/

Answer (score -1):

Try [Pydroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3), the best IDE on Android, autocompletion and code analysis works awesome, supports most of the libraries you need

Answer (score -2):

You need a Python Interpreter to run Python scripts,Pydroid Gives you access to compile  Python scipts and comes with pip,So you could Install new Python Modules,it's the only app that gives a real Experience of Programming using python.